# Prove that if $G$ is $k$-connected, then the join $K_1 + G$ is $(k + 1)$-connected

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, proof-explanation, connectedness

I am looking at the proof provided by another post:

**[Prove that if $G$ is a $k-connected$ graph, then $G \bigvee K_1$ is $k+1$ connected graph](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/962790/prove-that-if-g-is-a-k-connected-graph-then-g-bigvee-k-1-is-k1-connec)**

I am having trouble understanding the first case how $S-v$ turns out to be a vertex cut for the graph $G.$ I do not see how this could be the case, although I do understand that it would contradict the fact that $G$ is $k$-connected.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first case for [the answer there](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/963504/206402), $S$ is defined (for the purposes of contradiction) as a vertex cut set of $H:=G+K_1$ of size $k$ that contains $v\in K_1$. Removing $v$ leaves the full graph $G$ and a vertex cut $S-v$ of size $k{-}1$, which is a contradiction, since we are given that $G$ is $k$-connected.

Possibly it's easier to understand as a positive statement: since $v$ from $K_1$ connects to every vertex in $G$, a reduced graph can never be disconnected unless $v$ is removed. Thus any vertex cut set of $H$ must contain the vertex $v$ from $K_1$, and the rest of the cut set clearly requires at least $k$ more vertices due to the $k$-connected nature of $G$.

Comment: Okay, I get that this is a contradiction, but why would $S-v$ be a vertex cut of $G$ alone now? In general we are just saying the contradiction is we have a vertex-cut of size $k-1$ and applying this to $G$?

Comment: Are we not removing $v$ from the set and not the graph $H$?

Comment: We are implementing the vertex cut - first step, remove $v$ from $H$, leaving the rest of $S$ (=$S{-}v$) to remove from $G$.

Comment: I am not sure I follow because doesn't $S-v$ mean we are removing $v$ from the vertex-cut so it remains in the graph $H$?

Comment: No, that's after we have removed $v$ from $H$, describing what is left to do in implementing the vertex cut $S$.

Comment: I do not see $v$ being removed from the graph $H$ first. I see that they are considering the case of $v$ being a part of $S$ and then looking at what the set does if we remove it from the set? When $v$ is removed from the set it also implies it was removed from $H$?

Comment: Yes, they're following the process of "cutting" $H$. Remove a vertex from $H$ and obviously you can't remove it again, so it also is removed from the cut set in parallel.

Comment: So, in removing $v$ from $S$ they also removed it from $H$? What do you mean by removing it twice?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/74603/discussion-between-joffan-and-sam).